# Using chain homotopy equivalences of two chain complexes, show two spaces are homotopy equivalent.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $X$ be a simply connected CW-space with base point as a single $0$-cell . Let $C$ be the reduced cellular chain complex of $X$ (quotient of cellular chain complex of $X$ by the cellular chain complex of the base point). Let $D$ be another chain complex of free abelian groups where $D_k= 0$ for $k < 2.$

Show if $D$ is chain homotopy equivalent to $C$, then there exists a based CW-space $Y$ such that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$ and the reduced cellular chain complex of $Y$ is isomorphic to $D.$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ This type of problem is quite new for me.
$X$ is simply connected hence by cellular approximation, $X$ has no $1$-cell $\implies H_1(X)=0.$

Here, $C_k(X)=H_k(X^k,X^{k-1})$ thus $C_0(X)=\mathbb Z$ and $C_1(X)=0.$

Let $f,g : C\to D$ be chain homotopy equivalent maps. So there are morphisms $\Psi : D_n\to D_{n+1}, \Phi : C_n\to C_{n+1}$
such that :

$f_ng_n-id_{D_n}=\partial^D_{n+1}\Psi_n+\Psi_{n-1}\partial^D_n$ and analogously

$g_nf_n-id_{C_n}=\partial^C_{n+1}\Phi_n+\Phi_{n-1}\partial^C_n$ for all $n.$

And $f_ig_i=id_{D_i} ; g_if_i=id_{C_i}$ for $i=0,1.$

But, then how to construct such a space $Y$ ? I can't use any of there known theorems for homotopy theory .
Thanks in advance for a modest hint.

Comment: I disagree with your claim that $C_1(X)=0$. $X$ could very well have $1$-cells, so its 1-skeleton $X^1$ could have nontrivial homology.

Comment: $X$ is $1$-connected , so by cellular approximation, we can make $X$ homotopy equivalent to a space with no $1$-cells .

Comment: (a) So $X$ may have 1-cells, but I agree that it is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex without 1-cells. (b) $C_k(X)$ is free abelian on the $k$-cells, so once you know there are no 1-cells, you can immediately deduce that $C_1(X)=0$. That is, the part "thus $ C_0(X) = C_1(X) = 0$" is misleadingly phrased. (c) Finally, since $X$ has a $0$-cell, $C_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I mistook the value of $C_0(X).$

Comment: @JohnPalmieri,can you please give some hints ? This type of problem is quite new for me.